# Looping two cursors in same loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables; During a data conversion process a column in table 1 is updated with data from same column in table 2 but one of the condition is missed which updated multiple entries with same value.

```
Table 1:
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
abc    def    100    1.0    XYZ
abc    def    101    1.0    XYZ
abc    def    102    1.0    XYZ
bcd    dff    103    1.0    WXY
bcd    dff    104    1.0    WXY
bcd    dff    105    1.0    WXY

Table 2:
col1   col2   col3   col4
abc    def    1.0    XYZ    
abc    def    1.0    YZ1
abc    def    1.0    YZ2
bcd    dff    1.0    WXY
bcd    dff    1.0    WX1
bcd    dff    1.0    WX2
```

I would like to update the column 5 in table 1 with the data from column 4 in table 2.
Any help is appreciated.

Expected Table 1 after update

```
Updated Table 1
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
abc    def    100    1.0    XYZ
abc    def    101    1.0    YZ1
abc    def    102    1.0    YZ2
bcd    dff    103    1.0    WXY
bcd    dff    104    1.0    WX1
bcd    dff    105    1.0    WX3
```

Comment: Can you show us related code which you have tried so far?

Comment: How do you know which row of `table1` should be updated from which row of `table2`?  Neither table appears to have an obvious unique key.

Comment: Yes, currenlty there is no unique column in both the tables. The column 5 is supposed to be the unique column which was updated without considering the previous value during data conversion. There is no restriction on which row in col 5 in table 1 should be updated with the data in column 4 of table 2

Comment: Please provide us more details as is not as elaborated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE TABLE1 A
SET A.COL5 =(SELECT COL4 FROM TABLE2 B WHERE A.COL1=B.COL1 AND A.COL2=B.COL2 AND A.COL3=B.COL3 AND A.COL4=B.COL4)
```

I am not sure if I got your question but this seems to be the solution.